# Why is Leptospirosis so difficult to catch?

Tags: microbiology, epidemiology

I was on a small mammals training course and the professor was warning of the dangers of Leptospirosis. Apparently 5-40% of Rats have it and an unknown proportion of other animals. The warning sheet they handed out listed farmers, gardeners, etc as 'at risk' groups. I looked it up on the NHS website out of interest but it said there were only about 25 cases a year in the UK, even of the mild form.

I understand that it dies when it's dried out, but still, in notoriously rainy Britain, I can't seem to make sense of the numbers. There are at least half a million farmers in our country, probably a similar amount of gardeners, at least several thousand homeless and poverty stricken who must live in very close proximity to the huge urban Rat population, not to mention the potential for rodents to get into domestic water tanks. In rainy weather everything can stay wet for days. Also, if I remember rightly, an Olympic athlete recently died from it, so it obviously doesn't require a weak physiology to get in.

So, the question is, given what seems to me to be a massive prevalence (40% of all Rats), vast contact opportunities (all land workers during spells of wet weather), and seemingly a tough little organism (can kill an Olympic athlete), why is it so rare (25 cases in 70,000,000 people)?

Comment: Leptospira, the bacteria is largely found in the urine. So the urine from the rat has to get into cuts or wounds of a human. That seems rather unlikely. For such a thing to happen, you need ample rains, improper sewage and lots of rats. So apart from occupational groups, the disease also has an epidemic nature. During heavy rains in Mumbai, rodent infested sewers overflow and there's sudden spike in leptospirosis cases. I don't know the nos. but my micro txt calls it the most widespread zoonosis. Spells of wet weather aren't enough, there needs to be water logging combined with contamination.

Comment: Yes, Leptospirosis is, of course, a major problem in tropical areas, but as far as I know, there has never been an epidemic in Britain, yet we have some floods as well as all the other things I listed in my question. What puzzles me is there seems to be nothing in the bacterium's characteristics or mode of transmission that would account for the lack of epidemic in Britain. A little further reading I've done since asking the question seems to even imply that it can survive in moist soil http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/lab-bio/res/psds-ftss/msds95e-eng.php, we shouldn't even need a rainy season.

Comment: An epidemiologist must be able to answer this question but id like to point out that the presence of bacteria doesn't necessarily lead to infection. Something as ubiquitous as Clostridium tetani in the soil doesn't cause tetanus in everyone (even in pre-vaccination era).

Comment: That's true, but the mode of transmission with C.tetani is what prevents it from reaching epidemic scales, it requires a relatively deep wound. What I seem to be missing is the equivalent characteristic of Leptospires which prevents Leptospirosis from reaching epidemic proportions in Britain.

Comment: Both deep and superficial wounds can cause tetanus. In recent times superficial wounds have become the main mode infection, more than deep wounds. This may be because deeper wounds receive more attention. I know this is off-track but still...

Comment: No, not at all off-track, I see what you're saying, it may indicate that other pathogens share whatever it is that Leptospires have which make them more difficult to catch than their prevalence in the environment would at first suggest. Do you happen to know if Tetanus has a mild form? One theory I considered with Leptospirosis, is because it has a mild form, it is under-recorded and in fact thousands of people are catching it without even noticing (this would then tally with the prevalence). Of course this just moves the question to why the severe form is so rare.

Comment: Any inputs? @theforestecologist

Comment: Based on some climate informatics, however, using our examples of Mumbai and I'm going to use London here: It's always warmer in Mumbai, closer to an average of 30C compared to ~20C in London. And when it rains in Mumbai, it rains: 60-70mm rain average in London compared to 600mm or greater during the months it actually does rain in Mumbai. I'd also consider healthcare standard. There are many things in play that need considering.

Comment: Yes, I've read that the disease is more of a problem in Tropical areas, but I've not read anything to indicate why. As I said in my post, it is not killed by cold weather (certainly not 10-20C anyway) and it can already survive for many weeks in just damp mud, it doesn't need any rain at all let alone 600mm. What I'm really after is why, from a physiological point of view, the bacterium is so much worse off in temperate zones.

Comment: Let me simplify the question. Rodents getting into the cold water tank is a problem described by various plumbing books as "quite common". People, wash, bathe, brush teeth and occasionally drink this water. The incidence of Leptospirosis from unknown sources in the UK is fewer than ten (eliminating foreign travel, water-sports and occupational exposure). So the question is, how do we get from a "quite common" situation which provides direct water-bourne exposure to rodents, in a country of 70,000,000, to fewer than ten (if any) cases of Leptospirosis caused by this type of exposure?

Comment: I see no-one has been able to answer this, but just in case anyone is considering the question, I've just found an interesting set of data from the national archives on reported zoonosis in the UK. It records the ages, and often causes, of all reported cases of Leptospirosis. Using age as a proxy for domestic sources (a domestic source would affect all ages equally) it would seem, as far as records go back, that no-one has ever contracted Leptospirosis this way, so I'm looking to explain not just a low chance, but no chance at all.